# SIGSEGV raised by 32 bit application vs 64 bit applicationn

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, kernel

I've been learning buffer overflows and noticed something strange.

```
void vuln()
{
    char buf[180];

    gets(buf);
    puts(buf);

    return;
}

int main()
{
    __gid_t egid;

    setvbuf(stdout, 0x0, 2, 0);
    egid = getegid();
    setresgid(effective_gid, effective_gid, effective_gid);

    puts("You know who are 0xDiablos: ");
    vuln();
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code as 64 bit and 32 bit.

```
gcc test.c -fno-stack-protector -o 64bit.o
gcc test.c -fno-stack-protector -o 32bit.o -m32
```

I than passed more than 180 A's as input on the 32bit application under strace.

```
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x41414141} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
```

I then performed the same test on the 64bit application under strace.

```
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=NULL} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
```

Why does the 64 bit show that the invalid memory references was NULL, should't it be 0x41414141 like the 32bit SIGSEGV?

not sure if this matters but my kernel is 5.5.8.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. There's no reason to expect a particular result. Memory layout is probably different in the two architectures.

Comment: how many A's did you input? stack structure is probably bigger in 64 bit. anyway this depends on the compiler, on the architecture... those attacks are done on already existing programs.

Comment: I tried with a few megabytes worth of A's and got the same result.

Comment: The 64-bit variant would have twice as many `41` pairs in the address if you were successful.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the 64 bit show that the invalid memory references was NULL, should't it be 0x41414141

It shows NULL because processor doesn't actually execute the `CALL`, because the destination address is not in [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details).

Simplest program demonstrating this:

```
int main()
{
  int (*fn)(void) = (int(*)()) 0x4141414141414141;
  return fn();
}
```